# Python 3 dir() method called on null object

Tags: python-3.x

This isn't so much a question to help me figure out code, rather a question asking what the behavior of an object is. In python 3, there is a function

```
dir([object])
```

I am reading the python document on it, and it says it returns the names of the arguments attributes, more or less.  And if there is no argument, it returns the list of names in the current local scope.  So let's say, my only code I have is:

```
dir([nullObject])
```

I haven't initialized it at all in my code, so it should just be null.  Does the compiler see this as an error, or will it treat the function as if it was called without any arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "null object" in Python. There are unbound names, but those result in a `NameError` as normal.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Did not know that, thank you for the information!  Very new to Python (like today new).

Comment: You can learn quite a bit by having a play around in the REPL.

Comment: As [this article](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) explains, variables in Python are not like variables in other languages.